# Microsoft Hadoop Avro Serializer does not support IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, hadoop, avro, azure-hdinsight

I have a simlpe class that has a property type of IEnumerable While trying to create a serializer with reflection (see [Microsoft .NET SDK For Hadoop](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)) it fails with following exception.

> Could not find any matching known type for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.

But it works when string[] is used instead IEnumerable

Class used

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Field1;

    [DataMember]
    //public string[] Array1; This works
    public IEnumerable<string> Array1; //this doesn't
}
```

Code

```
public void CreateSerializer()
{
    var serializer = AvroSerializer.Create<MyClass>();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Why IEnumerable not supported or a workaround.

Comment: Any news on this? I have was about to make It serialize it but the deserializing it does not work.

Comment: I got a similar error about `no known type` for a list. Turns out that each type used in a collection, needed an attribute. For me, I added `[KnownType(typeof(List<MyCompany.TimedEvent>))]` to the class, just under `[DataContract]`. I'm guessing, but may be `[KnownType(typeof(IEnumerable<string>)]` would work. Weird that it wouldn't work out of the box for `string`s.

Comment: Same error, generator doesn't issue the full list of [KnownType(... for arrays (my type was two nested arrays, ).

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable type has not been enumerated, so the data within is not known.  It will only be known when it is enumerated.  This happens when you call, for example, ToArray() or ToList() on it.

Since it has not been enumerated it makes no sense to serialize it, it may not be possible to be enumerated after it is  deserialized because no data will have been preserved.

You will have to enumerate it before serializing, by converting to an Array or List or some other concrete collection type.